# Typescript path resulting in wrong import

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript (4.1.3) and I started using custom paths in tsconfig.json. Ever since, when I import any .ts file, if I dont use the whole path , I get the error:

> Error:(138, 33) TS2307: Cannot find module 'pages/foo/bar' or its corresponding type declarations.

To fix that I must add the prefix 'src/', so I get 'src/pages/foo/bar'. The project itself works fine, even with this TS Error.

Here is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "foo": [
            "bar.js"
        ]
    },
    "types": [
        "quasar",
        "node",
        "cypress"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es2018",
        "dom"
    ]
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
],
"extends": "@quasar/app/tsconfig-preset"
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`compilerOptions.baseUrl` is being prefixed to path specified in `import` statement to create path **relative** to the location of `tsconfig.json` file.

In your case the path to module bar.js in relation to `tsconfig.json` file is src/pages/foo/bar. So you either specify `./src` in `compilerOptions.baseUrl` or specify that complete path in `import` statement.

Comment: I see, but why this happens only if I add the "paths" configuration in tsconfig?

Comment: Not working, w/ tsc or w/ ts-loader.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be issue with your config `baseUrl:"."` , this means that js module resolution happens from current dir that's why your imports complaints to add src dir.

Make sure you point this config to src dir then all import resolution takes place from that dir. Example: `baseUrl:"./src"`

More details : https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl

Answer (score 0):

Just add "typescript-path-fix" into your task runner pipeline or call it just before compiling your code

Use this package to resolve your issue:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-path-fix